# I am getting wrong value of quarters

Tags: r

For below code i am getting wrong quarters. Please help  me with this issue

```
qy= cut.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(c("2015-09-01 IST","2016-08-1 IST")), breaks="quarter", labels=FALSE,include.lowest=T)
qy
# [1] 1 5
```

Comment: It looks correct.  What is the problem?  Also please indent your code 4 spaces in which case SO will format it for you.

Comment: Why i am getting  quarter value as '5' it should be max 4 for an year

Comment: It's the 5th level of the factor.  Remove `labels = FALSE` and look at the result.  Press Edit below the post to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

`cut.POSIXt` (with `labels=FALES`) gives you the quarters relative to the `min(X)` quarter - it starts at one with the earliest date and tells you the number of quarters between each date and that. So when you give dates in Q3 of two consecutive years, the first is 1, and the second is 4 quarters later, i.e. 5.

If you're trying to get the quarter within the year for each date use `quarters` or `lubridate::quarter`:

```
quarters(as.POSIXct(c("2015-09-01 IST","2016-08-1 IST")))
[1] "Q3" "Q3"
lubridate::quarter(as.POSIXct(c("2015-09-01 IST","2016-08-1 IST")))
[1] 3 3
```

Note that `quarters` comes out as a string starting with "Q", whereas `lubridate::quarter` comes out as an integer.